# How to read hibernate config file from user defined directory

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, toplink

I need to provide a jar file which provides an API to retrieve the records from the database using Hibernate.

For example I have an API:

```
public List getUsers(String locationOfHibernateConfigFile) {
}
```

I tried by passing the location of the config file with the complete path using `c:\hibernate-cfg.xml` as shown below:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                          .configure(C:\hibernate.cfg.xml).buildSessionFactory();
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

I am getting an error saying `c:\hibernate-cfg.xml is not found`.

Please provide me some pointers to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
    .configure("hibernate.primaryKeys.cfg.xml")
    .buildSessionFactory();
```

Where `hibernate.primaryKeys.cfg.xml` is a user-defined hibernate file.

This will work, but ensure `hibernate.primaryKeys.cfg.xml` is in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Well try it:

```
File file = new File("C:\hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(file).buildSessionFactory();
```

But it is not advisable to leave this type of configuration on C:.

Comment: @mohan Do you have all libraries of hibernate in your classpath? please check it.  Put this, directories with all jars: bytecode, jpa, optional, required; and jars: hibernate3.jar, log4j.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.6.2-sources.jar and slf4j-simple-1.6.2.jar.

Answer (score 1):

You can read file and properties:

Just put your file hibernate.cfg.xml into the resources folder.

```
Properties properties = new Configuration().configure().getProperties();

String driver = properties.getProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class");
String url = properties.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url");
String username = properties.getProperty("hibernate.connection.username");
String password = properties.getProperty("hibernate.connection.password");
```